# How to know if the chanting a phrase, require initiation or not?

Tags: mantras, shloka, stotra, initiation, vedic-chanting

I know that Mantras require initiation, especially those ones with Beeja Mantras.
but how do I know if a phrase is Mantra or Stotra or Shloka?

Is there any list of Mantra or Stotra which require initiation?

Is there any pattern, to recognize that, the phrase is a Mantra and require Initiation?

Comment: Any mantra cam be chanted without initiation but getting the right pronunciation is very important.